# send a form as an email under a unique user email (w/forwarding) using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces, sendgrid

As a User, I would like to submit a form that will send an email containing the submitted information in the form.

example:

User submission

```
{ 
  user_id: "25"
  user_name: "johnsmith"
  info: "hello world"
  to: "email@domain.com"
}
```

the objective is to send anemail the following format:

```
from johnsmith <johnsmith@appdomain.com>
to: email@domain.com
content: "hello world"
```

If one reply to the generated email aka johnsmith@appdomain.com, the app should be able to forward the email to the user-specific email example johnsmith@gmail.com

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: you can achieve this using sendgrid

Answer (score 0):

After saving the user you need to call the UserMailer from which you will be sending the data over the mail

```
UserMailer.send_data(user.id).deliver
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

 def send_data(user_data)
  @user = User.find_by(id: user_data) 
  @user_name = @user.user_name
  @content = @user.content
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Successful Signup")
 end
end
```

Please be aware to set the mailer configurations in the corresponding current environment(eg: development.rb)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Above defined instance variables(@user_name, @content) will be used in the html for sending corresponding data.